# Prevent JavaScript bubbling up in RAW JavaScript (not JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm trying to create a button-with-a-checkbox by creating a span containing some text and a checkbox input.

The interaction I want is that whenever the 'button' or the checkbox is clicked, the state of the checkbox toggles.

However, I am suffering from the bubble-up problem, and I can't figure out how to fix it as all solutions on here seem to be JQuery solutions - I'm looking to do this is raw JS.

What I have so far is:

HTML:

```
<span id="myCBbutton" class="CBbutton" onClick="toggleIt(event);">Toggle Me <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" onClick="toggleIt(event);event.stopPropagation();"></span>
```

CSS:

```
.CBbutton {
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: silver;
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

and JS:

```
function toggleIt(event) {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById('myCheckBox');

    if (checkBox.checked) {
        alert("before: it's checked!");
    } else {
        alert("before: NOT checked");
    }

    checkBox.checked = (checkBox.checked)?false:true;

    if (checkBox.checked) {
        alert("after: it's checked!");
    } else {
        alert("after: NOT checked");
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}
```

I've also created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fatmonk/pst7Lxd3/).

I guess fromother questions and answers that the solution is something to do with either `event.preventDefault()` or `event.stopPropagation()` with or without a `return false` but I just can't get this to work.

Comment: Post the code here, not just at the fiddle

Comment: Your issue isn't with propagation, it is that the checkbox status is changed before the click event fires the handler. So when you click the checkbox itself, its status is already "checked" by the time the event reaches the handler, which then turns around and unchecks it. If you click on the span, your checkbox is not yet checked, and the handler checks it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.stopPropagation()` is the good code, but your problem is elsewhere.

When you do this : `checkBox.checked = (checkBox.checked)?false:true;`, the browser fire a new `click` event and this one is bubbling to the parent.

But anyway, Luizgrs solution is the better i think.

Comment: Assigning to `.checked` does not trigger a click event.

Comment: Say that to firefox :(

Comment: @Magus Firefox says: [Programatically setting value does not fire change or click handlers](http://jsfiddle.net/7rs5b4p1/1/)

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer as it directly addresses the issue in my question - however I have gone for Luizgrs' `<label>` solution in my project as it is much neater.

Comment: The real issue is that the checkbox's checked status is stored before the event handler fires, which results in the checkbox's checked status being reverted whenever it is clicked directly.

Answer (score 4):

To achieve what you want you can use an `label` instead of going to Javascript:

```css
.CBbutton {
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: silver;
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
Label with checkbox inside:<br>
<label id="myCBbutton" class="CBbutton">Toggle Me <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox"></label>
<br><br>
Label with checkbox outside<br>
<label class="CBbutton" for="myCheckBox2">Toggle Me</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox2">
```

But replying to your question, `stopPropagation` is what would make an event do not propagate to parent's handlers.

Comment: Much better than what the OP was trying to do

Comment: Kudos for the use of `label` as an alternative here.

Comment: Nice! I like that. I've gone for this solution in my code as it is much neater (so have an upvote) but I'll accept Magus's answer as that directly answers the issue with the code I'd written.

Comment: After further investigation - I've updated your snippet to include the `for` attribute for the second checkbox as it's required when the `input` tag is not inside the `label` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`

[Sample Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AmitGoda/9asgw6go/2/)

[Documentation Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you [use a label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33172990/227299) as suggested by Luizgrs

However, the problem with your code is that even though you are preventing propagation (the handler on the span is not called when you click the checkbox), the click on checkbox is going to change its checked status and your code is then switching it back. There are ways to fix it but it's not worth it, a `<label>` does the hard work for you